# How make a http post with Dio using data raw in flutter?

Tags: flutter, http, dio

I'm trying to do a dio post request and I need to specify the body as raw-data Post

[image]

```js
Response response = await (await init()).post(url, data: {
        "token": token,
        "code": formol}
        );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to encode it as a Json:

```
var json =  {
  "code": "xxxxxxxxx",
  "token": "-------------",
}; 
...
Response response = await _dio.post(url,
  options: Options(headers: {
    HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json",
  }),
  data: jsonEncode(json),
);
```